# ANTLR v3 C# namespaces

Tags: namespaces, antlr

Hopefully this is a really quick one ;)  I have written a lexer / parser specification in ANTLR3, and am targeting the CSharp2 target.  The generated code works correctly, but I can't get ANTLR to put the C# output into a namespace.

The relevant section of the Grammar file is as follows:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

options
{
    language = CSharp2;
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}
```

To generate the correct namespace, I have tried:

```
@namespace { MyNamespace }
```

and

```
@lexer::namespace { MyNamespace }
@parser::namespace { MyNamespace }
```

but both of these generate errors, claiming that the file has no rules.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this for a combined lexer and parser (and it generates the namespace correctly):

```
grammar Test;

options
{
    language=CSharp2;
}

@lexer::namespace {
    My.Name.Space
}

@parser::namespace {
    My.Name.Space
}


DIGIT   :   '0'..'9';

simple  :    DIGIT EOF;
```

So i wonder why your version didn't work - maybe you want to try this simple example and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the @namespace directive needs to be placed AFTER the tokens{} block.  All good now...

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out the hard way. Nearly pulled all my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

With `language = 'CSharp3';` (and CSharp2 as well), you can do:

```
@lexer::namespace {
    My.Name.Space
}

@parser::namespace {
    My.Name.Space
}
```

which generates:

```
} // namespace 
 My.Name.Space <-- compile error here
```

at the end of lexer and parser code. If I write:

```
@lexer::namespace {My.Name.Space}

@parser::namespace {My.Name.Space}
```

it works fine and generates:

```
} // namespace My.Name.Space <-- within the line comment, no error of course
```